# get query result with page title in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i wanna access to an item details by wp query with page title

i tried this codes but failed
it shows just hello world and his content (first post , id=1) 
please help me to write this

```
          <form method="GET" action="">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="product">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="compare">
    </form>
 <?php  
   if(isset($_GET['product']) && !empty($_GET['product'])) {

    $product_title = $_GET['product'];

    $prdocut_id = get_page_by_title($product_title);

    $args = array('page_id' => $product_id);
    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if($query) :
        while ($query->have_posts()) :
            $query->the_post();
            the_title();
              the_content();
        endwhile;
    endif;
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_page_by_title` returns an *OBJECT* by default as you can read [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title).

Try to change your code as the following:

```
 $product = get_page_by_title( $product_title );
 $product_id = $product->ID;    

 /*See here the possible WP Query args http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query*/
 $args = array(
      'page_id' => $product_id
      'post_type' => 'cars',
 );

  $query = new WP_Query($args);

 /* rest of your code */
```

Comment: btw im using custom post type 'cars' , i changed $args= array('p'=>$product_id) and $product = get_page_by_title($product_title,OBJECT,'cars') but didnt get result what should i do?

Comment: This was not part of the question, but you have to change your `$args` array according to your needs. See above the updated answer.